# Use Laravel to Log Hacking Activity

Tags: php, laravel, security

Recently I have a few websites frequently being hacked by hacker. Once it is being hacked, the hacker will upload a series of "hacker" files into the server root folder. After I cleaned the website, it will happen again several months later. This happen repeat again and again.

The problem is I don't know how the website is being hacked. Is it possible for us to use Laravel log to do the tracing of hacking? If yes, how can we do it?

Comment: use your server logs to check for access and uploads/weird activities. this question is not suited for stackoverflow

Comment: Server logs could help to find the entry point(s), as already mentioned.
But IMO the main problem is how the most hostings/server are configured - if you'd limit webserver user "write" access to only certain dirs like maybe cache and uploads - it could drastically decrease the possible "hacking vectors". 
Also you could start to monitor app dir for a new files and get notified when something new appears there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem sounds like XSS issues: cross-scripting via any kind of input fields or parameters passed in the URL and/or form POST that are not protected.
The other aspect if to check if the different passwords are strong enough.